# Interrupt calculations without losing memory

Tags: abort, quiet

Writing:

```
a = 1;
Do[If[n == 3, Quit[]], {n, 5}];
Print["Hello!"];
```

the calculations stop and the following code does not execute: perfect, that's what I want!

Unfortunately, in this way you lose memory, as `a` is no longer equal to `1`. How can I fix it?

Comment: Maybe "Break" is what you want?

Comment: @DanielHuber: no, because then it prints `Hello!`.

Comment: This seems very much like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Also, procedural way of programming in Mathematica can usually be replaced with other construction. Anyway, if you insist on procedural way, [`Break`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Break.html) is certainly a solution, together with a flag variable: `noBreak = True; Do[If[n == 3, noBreak = False; Break[]], {n, 5}]; If[noBreak, Print["Hello!"]];`. Note that `Quit` doesn't "stop the calculation", it kills the whole kernel, which is something you probably never really want to do in your code ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not want some code not executing after leaving the Do loop, you can use Catch and Throw. Here is an example:

```
a = 1;
Catch[
  Do[If[n == 3, Throw[1]], {n, 5}];
  Print["Hello!"];
  ];

Print["a=", a];

(*a=1*)
```